# Form in Element instead of View

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have to do one page web application in cakePHP. I have template where are put all divs and from jQuery then show or hidden appropriate div. I have two div with forms to store some data in db. I crated elements for my div-s, and then in my layout, in each div i put

< ? php echo $this->element('register'); ?>

I created form in element, a same way in view.

```
<?php $customers = $this->requestAction('customers/add'); ?>

<div class="customers form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Customer'); ?>



    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('salutation', array(
                    'options' => array('Mr' => 'Mr', 'Mrs' => 'Mrs', 'Ms' => 'Ms')
                ));
        echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('required' => true));
                echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array('required' => true));
        echo $this->Form->input('street', array('required' => true));
                echo $this->Form->input('zip_city', array('required' => true));
                echo $this->Form->input('country', array('required' => true));
                echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('required' => true));
                echo $this->Form->input('email', array('required' => true));
    ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end($options); ?>

</div>
```

My controller for adding data in db:

```
public function add(){        
        if($this->request->is('customer')) {
            $this->Customer->create();
            if($this->Customer->save($this->request->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('Register successiful');
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to register!');
        }
    }
```

I think that is my problem in this line:

```
if($this->request->is('customer')) {
```

If I remove if-statement, I succedd to store data in table, but stored and more blank rows.

I appreciate every suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Is there a question somewhere? And maybe you should explain what you expect your various code fragments to do, especially the calls to `requestAction()` and `CakeReqeust::is()` (what does your `customer` detector look like, if it exists at all?), as both seem to be just wrong.

Comment: I can't store data in db. How can I do this? I use element insted view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to test if the request is post or not , not if it's an object :
if($this->request->is('post'))

Comment: Yes, that is problem. Thank you very much!

Correct:
if($this->request->is('post'))